# Why can not break out of the while loop in which many child threads are forked?

Tags: c, loops, concurrency, fork

In my program, each time the user types a message via stdin, the code reads it in, and calls fork() to create a new (child) process. This child process sends data (the user's typed in message) using a server socket.

To end the client process, I would like the user to type "quit". At which point, I would like my code to exit the While(1) loop, wait for all the child processes to finish processing (so leaving behind no orphaned/zombie processes). And then at this point, when all the child processes have finished and exited, I would like the program to end.

However now and with my code as shown below, when the user types "quit", although the child processes terminate successfully, the loop starts over. Does any one know what am I doing wrong in the code?

```
int status = 0;
while (1) {

    // Read request from standard input
    printf("Enter a message: ");
    memset(out_buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    fgets(out_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1, stdin);
    out_buffer[strcspn(out_buffer, "\r\n")] = 0;

    // Spawn new process to handle new client
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
        printf("[-]Error spawning child process for new client.\n");
        continue;
    }
    // Child process
    else if (pid == 0) {
        // ...
        if (input_status == -2) {
            printf("[-]Disconnected from server.\n");
            close(socket_fd);
            termination_call = 1;
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    if (termination_call == 1) {
        printf("[-]Client terminating...\n");
        break;
    }

}

// Wait for all child processes to exit
while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0);
return 0;
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the length you pass to [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) *includes* the terminator. No need for the `- 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for the `"quit"` command *in the parent*.

When you fork a new process, it runs independent of the parent process, and no data is shared between them.

If you want to share data then consider threads.

Comment: So if the child process changed a variable, e.g. ` termination_call = 1;` it won't change for the parent?

Comment: @Wizard That's correct. The new process gets a new and separate memory map that is independent of the parent.

Comment: I see! Thank you. One other thing, would that mean I would need to close the socket in both the parent and child processes when I am exiting?

Comment: @Wizard Yes you need to close the socket in both processes. In fact, if the parent process doesn't use the socket any more after the call to `fork` you can close it immediately.